# Google Script Quota Issues: Gmail Read

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, quota

I'm having a bit of trouble with my google script code.  I'm trying to make a script that will automatically take any email that is sent with 'Events' in the subject and parse the text to add it to the calendar.  I have a filter that will add the email to the label 'Events', then remove the label.

The script is working fine and is posted below.  I have it triggering every minute.  However, every day I get a huge failure notification email that I've exceeded the quota for gmail reads on line 4 [GmailApp.getUserLabelbyName].  I tried googling and I couldn't find more specifics.

So, according to the quota website I have a limit of 10,000 reads per day.  This has been failing with no emails at all in the 'Events' bin, so no actual emails appear to be read.  The calendar should be accessing it once per minute, i.e. 1,440 times a day.

So why am I getting the quota failure for gmail read?  Does 'gmail reads' mean accesses to gmail (getting the label variable) or reading email bodies (getThreads) or both?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

function MakeEvents() {

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Events");            
if (label) {
  var threads = label.getThreads();    
  for (var x in threads) {      
    var messages = threads[x].getMessages();

    for (var y in messages) {

    var myHTMLContent = messages[y].getBody();
    textContent=getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(myHTMLContent, true).getElement());

    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventFromDescription(textContent);  

    }      
    threads[x].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

}

```
function getTextFromNode(x) {
switch(x.toString()) {
case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
default: return '';
```

}
}